# Retrieve the generated thumbnails for sorl

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl-thumbnails with my django project. Is there a way to retrieve the generated thumbnails of an image ? I've using the get_thumbnails method but in each call of it, it generate a new thumbnail. Some idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the redis install for KVStore? If you are using key value store, by default the template access should [fetch from the data store](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#model-examples). Have you tried something like `KVStore.objects.filter(key__startswith='filename')` ?